# Ctrl + S is not working as a horizontal split in VIM when using CommandT

Tags: vim, macvim

I've been tweaking my `~/.vim` quite a lot lately, and it seems that I broke something.

I'm using the CommandT plugin, which when the search is open allows for the following:

- enter - open the file in current buffer
- Ctrl + S - open the file in horizontal split window
- Ctrl + V - open the file in vertical split window

The problem is, that Ctrl + S suddenly stopped working in terminal VIM, only Ctrl + V is working. At first I thought I broke something in my general config, but then I tried it in MacVim, and Ctrl + S works just fine.

I'm not aware of having set anything specific only to the terminal VIM.

**Is there any way that I can tell, if a key is being rebound to something else and where is that happening?**

btw, my `~/.vim` is a fork of Janus with most stuff removed and changed, I'm keeping it mostly for the `Rakefile` for installing plugins. [here's the repo](https://github.com/darthdeus/janus)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 24):

I've found solution for this problem here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34503

Just put in your .bashrc / .zshrc this line of code:

```
stty -ixon -ixoff
```

Comment: Wow dude, you seriously saved me becoming crazy! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can list all current mappings by typing `:map` inside the command window.

You could also clear all maps using `:mapclear` and then map `<C-S>` again.

It could be that you vimrc contains alternate maps depending on the environment. Look for things like `has("gui_running")`.

Finally when running MacVim `gvimrc` is sourced vs. `vimrc` when running vim in the terminal.

Depending on the differences in both of those, mappings and other features will change.

I noticed, that you are talking about <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key in the title, but about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in your description. The <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key does not work in terminal vim.

If you are talking about the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key, consult my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514533/97443) to a similar question.

Comment: The Cmd in title was just a typo. I tried using `:map`, but it doesn't even show the `<C-v>`, which works. I also don't see any other mappings to either `<C-v>` or `<C-s>`. Isn't it possible that they're set somehow differently in the plugin itself?